# unknown directive "upload_progress" in Nginx using Upload Progress Module

Tags: nginx

I am trying to create progress bar functionality for my laravel app hosted in nginx. it is first time I am using nginx and noticed it is not easy to create upload progress for your uploads.
As said in this [tutorial](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload_progress/#configuration-example) the only way to create this we need "nginx-upload-progress-module". To install this module I followed this [tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/displaying-upload-progress-with-nginx-on-debian-wheezy). But when I try test nginx config I face `unknown directive "upload_progress"`.

this is my configuration:

```
upload_progress proxied 1m;

server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
 server_name  mydomain.com;
 client_max_body_size 0;


 root /var/www/mydomain.com/public;

 index index.php index.html;

 location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

      # track uploads in the 'proxied' zone
      # remember connections for 30s after they finished
        track_uploads proxied 30s;
 }

 location ^~ /progress {
        # report uploads tracked in the 'proxied' zone
         report_uploads proxied;
    }

 location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed by `apt update`. Perhaps there was an error that got fixed by update. Or maybe because I have removed nginx and installed nginx-extra afterwards cause some errors, which needed an update to fix. Also my configuration was wrong and the correct configuration is this:

```
upload_progress uploads 1m;

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com;
  client_max_body_size 0;


root /var/www/example.com/public;

index index.php index.html;

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ^~ /progress {
     # report uploads tracked in the 'uploads' zone
     upload_progress_json_output;
     report_uploads uploads;
 }

location ~ \.php$ {

include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

# track uploads in the 'uploads' zone
# remember connections for 30s after they finished
track_uploads uploads 30s;
}

}
```